# iOS 8 Autolayout - Dynamically Resizing 4 Square Views

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a view which contains a square subview (gray). This square subview then contains four smaller squares (blue):

[image]

Each of the squares are pinned to the top or bottom of the superview, and the left or right of the superview. For example, the top-left square has a constraint which pins the leading space to the superview and another constraint which pins the top space to the superview. Similarly, the bottom-right has constraints which pin the bottom and trailing spaces to the superview.

I am having real difficultly implementing constraints which will result in the squares resizing based upon the screen size. I have put horizontal and vertical spacing constraints between the squares, but that results in a warning that the content compression resistant priority on one of the squares needs to be reduced. When it's reduced, that square becomes tiny as the other square takes over all the space.

I just want each of the squares to be an equal size and resized by autolayout to fit the screen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all of the squares and apply Equal Widths and Equal Heights constraints to them all. Then, for one of the squares, apply an Aspect Ratio constraint to keep its width and height equal to each other. Finally, add a single space constraint between any two adjacent squares.

Those along with the constraints to pin each square to its corner of the superview should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the constraints in your image, I have added four space constraints with value 20 between adjacent squares, and align horizontal center of two squares on the right. You can refer to the below image.

[image]